# Call a c# function inside success function of ajax call in mvc4

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

I have made an ajax call on the success of that call I need to load values from a c# function into a java script variable. The code is below:

```
function successful(data) {
  @{bool mybool = Model.isTest()}
  var temp   = @mybool
}
```

But this function i.e `isTest()` is called on page load though the function is not included inside `$(document).ready()` function. I'm using mvc 4 razor engine.

**UPDATE:**

Razor loads the page first after that the Html is rendered. So there
is no way to call the c# function directly.

An ajax call has to be made to the function from the success function also.

Comment: it will be called because razor code is executed at view rendering time

Comment: oh any way to make it load later as in again when the call is made?

Comment: save he data of Model.isTest() into some objects and try to use it later on

Comment: on success you have to send an ajax call if data is needed on runtime from c# side

Comment: @Alpesh data loads into the function after the success function

Comment: @EhsanSajjad i dnt want do make an ajax call. rather i cant make an ajax call since the model cannot be accessed using a url

Comment: put your whole code here. ajax call function also